# Cannot input positive number when using NSNumberFormatter?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsnumberformatter

I'm using `NSNumberFormatter` for my `NSTextField` to make numbers like `1.23` display as `+1.23` and `-1.23` as `-1.23`. Everything works fine, until I tried to input directly into the text field.

If I typed in `1.23` and hit return, the form rejected the number by complaining the invalid format. What is wrong here?

I've set the format in IB completely, the the `Format(+)` field is `+0.00`, and `Format(-)` field is `-0.00`. I've also restricted the `Fraction Digits` to 2, `Positive Prefix` to `+` and `Negative Prefix` to `-` respectively.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it like this:

[image]